# react use .map() with useState

Tags: reactjs

**index.js**

```
const [questionRepliesAll, setQuestionRepliesAll] = useState([])

const [questionReplies, setQuestionReplies] = useState({
    replies: [
        {
            desc: 'hello word 1'
        },
        {
            desc: 'hello word 2'
        }
    ],
    reply_users: [
        {
            user: 1
        },
        {
            user: 2
        }
    ]
})

questionReplies.replies.map((reply, i) => {
    setQuestionRepliesAll([...questionRepliesAll, {'reply': desc, user_id: questionReplies.reply_users[i].user])})
```

**results**

```
[{reply: 'hello word 1', user_id: 1}, {reply: 'hello word 2', user_id: 2}] // expected

[] // actual result
```

**first implementation**

```
const combined = questionReplies.replies.map((reply, i) => {
                    return {'reply': desc,
                    user_id: questionReplies.reply_users[i].id}
                })
setQuestionRepliesAll(combined)
```

Basically, I want to combine 2 arrays into 1 and add it to questionRepliesAll, i tried adding it with just assigning the combined array to a variable ahnd then setting it `setQuestionRepliesAll(combined)` but that threw errors when i tried using .map() which was `Objects are not valid as a React child`, go down below to see what I tried doing at first, any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `Objects are not valid as a React child` error has to do with *how* you are rendering *something*. Your `setQuestionRepliesAll(combined)` version seems fine other than not ensuring all arrays are of equal length (or using proper null checks). Can you update your question to include how you are rendering whatever it is that you are rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `for loop` for this functionality.

```js
let arr = {
    replies: [
        {
            desc: 'hello word 1'
        },
        {
            desc: 'hello word 2'
        }
    ],
    reply_users: [
        {
            user: 1
        },
        {
            user: 2
        }
    ]
}
let formattedArray = [];
for(i=0;i<arr.replies.length;i++){
  formattedArray.push({reply:arr.replies[i].desc,user:arr.reply_users[i].user})
}
console.log(formattedArray)
```

Implementation in your case :

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [questionRepliesAll, setQuestionRepliesAll] = useState([])
    
  const [questionReplies, setQuestionReplies] = useState({
      replies: [
          {
              desc: 'hello word 1'
          },
          {
              desc: 'hello word 2'
          }
      ],
      reply_users: [
          {
              user: 1
          },
          {
              user: 2
          }
      ]
  });

  useEffect(()=>{
    let formattedArray =[]
    for(var i=0;i<questionReplies.replies.length;i++){   
      formattedArray.push({reply:questionReplies.replies[i].desc,user:questionReplies.reply_users[i].user})
    }
    setQuestionRepliesAll(formattedArray);  
  },[questionReplies])


  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{questionRepliesAll.map((item,key)=><li>user {item.user} ,  reply : {item.reply}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The key to your solution is setting state **one time**, *after* the loop has completed. Using `for` or `map` or even `forEach` doesn't make a difference as long as that is true